# Availabilty of other Putty like applications

Tags: windows-xp, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best SSH client for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/41326/whats-the-best-ssh-client-for-windows)

Hi All,

I would like to know if there is any other Application like Putty which can be used in windows which has a much better appearance and UI.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the actual tools (install MinGW or the like).  By this you will have a short learning period, but will come to appreciate the tools more and be able to use some pretty advanced things easily.